# Ember.js Dynamic Segments Without Nested Routes

Tags: ember.js

You guys may need more details to answer this, but I figured it might be simple. I'm using Ember Data and the fixture adapter.

This correctly maps the URL to each item in my model.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('quotes', function(){
    this.resource('quote', {path: '/:quote_id' })
  });
});

App.QuotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend ({
    model: function(){
        return App.Quote.find();
    }
});
```

But this does not.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('quotes', {path: '/:quote_id' });
});

App.QuotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend ({
    model: function(){
        return App.Quote.find();
    }
});
```

Does Ember only know to return App.Quote.find(quote_id) if it's a nested resource?

Comment: what about `this.route('quotes', {path: '/:quote_id' });`?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.`

Comment: and this `this.resource('quotes', {path: '/qoutes/:quote_id' });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller for your route in the second example will be generated as an `Ember.ArrayController`, which will mismatch with the controller generated for your '/:quote_id' path, as it's a singleton.

What happens if you pass a single model, by using `return App.Quote.find(1);` or something that will return one record.

I am still trying to understand what exactly you want to happen with that second code example. what kind of logic are you expecting?

Comment: In the first example, if I go to whatever.com/#/quotes/1 it returns the first record from my fixture data. In the second example, it doesn't. It doesn't return anything, it tells me it `Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.`I really just wanted to understand why they behaved differently.

Comment: There's difference in behavior, because in the first example an array of models is loaded into (automatically created) `Quotes` controller of type `Ember.ArrayController`, and the route supports the array-to-singleton process that is implicit to your definition of the route, and automatically loads the first record from the array into the `Ember.ObjectController` created for the `Quote` controller.